# How to use constants with Request in Laravel5

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to upgrade my Laravel4 app to Laravel5.

In my Laravel4 app, I use `app/config/constants.php` file and difine constants by using Request class.

```
if (Request::is('admin/*'))
{
    define('PATH', 'admin')
}else
{
    define('PATH', 'public')
}
```

and read it in `app/start.php`.

```
require __DIR__.'/../app/config/constants.php';
```

These constants are used in controllers, models, commands, views, and files in 'app/config' directory.

In Laravel5, how to read this file?

I tried:
1, added it in `config` directory and changed `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "config/constants.php"
    ]
}
```

I got error: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Request' not found`

2, added it in `config` directory and changed `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
    require __DIR__.'/../config/constants.php';
}
```

I got same error:  `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Request' not found`

Thanks,

Comment: hello maybe you should add `use Illuminate\Http\Request; ` into your constants.php file

Comment: I tried, and got new error.
  `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration::retrieveItem() in /home/hirai/l5mens/mens_webapp/ven  
  dor/compiled.php on line 2360`
It migth be not able to make instance of Request class...

Comment: when you get error in compiled.php try to clear it, run `php artisan optimize` command

Comment: run `php artisan optimize` and cleared `compiled.php`, but it didn't work. I think this approach is wrong essentialy... I will try another method to use these constants. But thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\Request` instead of `Request`
And you don't need to add constants.php to the composer json
use `\Config::get('constants.CONST_NAME')` helper function to ge const value and also you can use `const` keyword to define constants instead of `define()`

Comment: I tried, and got same error. `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Request' not found`.
Later I would rewrite codes using constants, but I want to use `define` currently because it would take lot of time.